# pm2 disconnect kills current running process

Tags: node.js, sails.js, pm2

hey stackoverflow community,

i have running a app with pm2, in this app it has a rest api with witch i can install other apps from a source. the install part works fine but on the end of the script i call pm2 programmatically to start the new process, after start the script kill pm2 the app with the api.

here is my startup code:

```
pm2.connect(function(err) {

     pm2.startJson(path, function(err, proc) {
        if (err) throw new Error('err');

        // Disconnect to PM2
        pm2.disconnect(function() { 

        process.exit(0);

        });
    });

});
```

why kill pm2 my current running process?

thanks for help

Comment: Why are you `process.exit(0)` when disconnected?

Comment: i copy this from the examples, but i testing this without the ` process.exit(0);` and the result is the same. i testing this without the `pm2.disconnects({})`, and this result is also the same.

Comment: What do you wish to do after you launched the process? Your app has an http server or something like that?

Comment: the app have a REST api to install other node js applications on the server. yes after installation shall run the http server continue run